# How do I get around Angular undoing my monkey patching with its own monkey patching?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, xmlhttprequest, monkeypatching

I'd like to intercept XHR requests for the Google Maps API so I can run them through my own proxy server as a way of keeping my API key private.

Angular has its own `HttpInterceptor`s, but they'll only intercept XHR requests which are made using Angular's `HttpClient`, not any requests made outside of the Angular framework by the Maps API. I'd think that monkey patching `XMLHttpRequest.open()` would be the best way to get at the requests going to the Maps API, which I've done like this:

```
  var oldXHROpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, username, password) {
    console.log(url);
    return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

The above code is placed in a `<script>` in the `<head>` section of my `index.html`, so it's definitely executed before any Angular code is executed.

The patch works... for a short time. I see URLs for a few assets loaded by my code logged out, but then this message appears:

`Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.`

After that just one more URL gets logged, and that's the last intercept I make. XHR requests continue to be processed, but my patch never sees them happen.

I'm sure this has something to do with zone.js, but I still don't understand how it could happen. Since I redefine `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` before Angular or zone.js even get a chance to see the original `open()` function, which is tucked away in the `oldXHROpen` variable, how does a direct connection to the native `open()` ever manage to happen again, bypassing my patch?

Comment: Just to throw some ideas: it's not necessarily connecting open back to native, it can just prevent calling your patched method

Comment: Ive tried to reproduce it but couldn't: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-mo2on . Maybe problem is in another castle

Comment: Did you try Angular's own `proxyConfig` mechanism? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: @Andrey, even in my case *some* interception happened, it just stopped after a few times. I suppose it might even be particular to the development environment, because the last request logged is to localhost, I think it's one of the calls used to check if the app should restart because the code might have changed.

Comment: @mbojko, I haven't yet, but I'll look at that in more detail later. At a quick glance I can't tell whether that proxy goes through HttpClient or not. If it uses HttpClient, it's not going to help here.

Comment: @@mbojko, I  just looked at your link some more, and unfortunately that's just a proxy for the node server, not something that runs in the web browser, where I need it for my particular problem. It's still very useful information, however, because I can definitely see how that would help in some situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I was laboring under the false premise that the client side of the Google Maps API would have to make XHR requests to get its work done.

It doesn't. It's all done by loading images, CSS, and fonts, with a little JSONP thrown in.

My monkey patching actually does work, and *doesn't* get undone by Angular.